# RemoveEventListner Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, touch-event

I'm adding an event listener for a touchmove and then removing it. Can someone please tell me whats wrong. The add event works fine but I cannot remove it and it is making my program lag like crazy because of all the event listeners in there.

```
function init() {
    var node = document.getElementById('playArea');
    node.addEventListener('touchmove', startGame);
    node.addEventListener('touchend', endGame)

}

function endGame() {
    var node = document.getElementById('playArea');
    node.removeEventListener('touchmove', removed, false);
    node.removeEventListener('touchend', removed, false);
}

function removed() {
    console.log('event removed');
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Because you're passing an entirely different function? If any arbitrary function could be passed, then why would they require a function at all?

Comment: There's a typo in `toucmove`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeEventListener` takes as its second argument *the same function* that was passed to `addEventListener`, so it knows which event listener to remove - the whole point of using `add/removeEventListener` over `.onEvent =` is because you can have multiple handlers for the same event.

```
node.removeEventListener("touchmove", startGame);
node.removeEventListener("touchend", endGame);
```

This removes the events. If you want, you can then add `removed` as a new event listener, but only if you actually need it.

Comment: how would i do this with if the function is inside the statement. eg.   node.removeEventListener('touchmove', function() {play game code})

Comment: You can't. If you use an anonymous function, you are making the assumption that you will not need to remove it. Assign the function to a variable and use that.

Comment: I put the function into a variable as you suggested and it worked perfectly. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo :

```
function init() {
    var node = document.getElementById('playArea');
    node.addEventListener('touchmove', startGame);
                               ^
    node.addEventListener('touchend', endGame)

}
```

Comment: typed this up by hand. sorry but thats not the problem. thanks for catching that though!